# Vertical gap between SVG and DOM

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG embedded inside HTML like this:

```
<p>Before SVG</p>
<svg viewBox="-1 -1 19 6">
    <g>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="0.4"></circle>
        <circle cx="17" cy="0" r="0.4"></circle>
        <circle cx="0" cy="4" r="0.4"></circle>
        <circle cx="17" cy="4" r="0.4"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
<p>After SVG</p>
```

I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnddcc/AG7xf/) of it.

In Google Chrome 30.0.1599.101 there is a big vertical gap / space between `Before SVG` and the SVG and between the SVG and `After SVG`. In Firefox 24 and IE 11 there is no vertical gap.

Is it possible to remove those gaps in chrome? I want the `svg` to be as big as the `g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird behavior..

The `height` seems to stretch to `100%` therefore creating this vertical gap by extending the vertical alignment of the `viewBox`. By setting `width:100%`, and `height:0%` this behavior is overwritten.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9BgKS/) - appears to work in Chrome/FF/IE

Additionally, the `p` has a default `margin`. Reset those to `0px`.

Note: In the above example - I tweaked the `cy` values of the `circles` in order to eliminate all the gaps. Here is an example without that. [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nCZnP/) - there is still a slight gap, however, it is nowhere near what it was before.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the miny value, and it seems to have removed the gap:

```
<svg viewBox="-1 4 19 6">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AG7xf/1/

Comment: It also cuts the `svg` off at certain viewports.

Comment: What browser did you use? I still see the gap in your fiddle.

Comment: I tested in Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a width and height.  So the SVG is defaulting to `width="100%"` `height="100%"`.  Just add a width and height, like so:

```
<svg viewBox="-1 -1 19 6" width="20px" height="7px">
    <g>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="0.4"></circle>
        <circle cx="17" cy="0" r="0.4"></circle>
        <circle cx="0" cy="4" r="0.4"></circle>
        <circle cx="17" cy="4" r="0.4"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Although at 20pxx7px it's a bit hard to see.  I'm assuming that's what you meant by "svg as big as the g".

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AG7xf/3/